# Looping over multiple URLs with a CSV database and regex

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I am trying to get a list of URLs from a parent database that are constructed of two different keys:

1. The relevant key to the sub folder
2. The pertinent key to the specific file

The sub folder key is held in a CSV file and so the concatenation is relatively simple:

```
csv <- read.csv("raw.csv")
vec <- csv$col1

URLs <- paste0("https://www.abc-corp.com/data/", vec, "/gotit/")
```

This returns a list of partial URLs but then it gets tricky.

The next section is a block of digits with 5 irrelevant ones, the year anotated in shorthand, then three more, e.g [https://www.abc-corp.com/data/1234/gotit/1234522123"](https://www.abc-corp.com/data/1234/gotit/1234522123%22)

I've tried:

```
URLs <- paste0("https://www.abc-corp.com/data/", vec, "/gotit/", "\d\d\d\d\d", "22", "\d\d\d")
```

and been told:

```
Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\d\d"
```

It seems to be putting in an extra speech mark as well as not recognising the regex.

Comment: The backslash is an escape character for both R strings and regex. Because of this, you need to double-escape things with two backslashes.

Comment: (You may also prefer to use quantifiers rather than repeating \\d a lot, `"\\d{5}"` means 5 `\\d`s)

Comment: When I run it to download them, I get errors ````Error in download.file(URLs[I], destfile = paste0("Scrape", : cannot open URL 'https://www.abc-corp.com/data/1234/gotit/\\d{5f}22\\d{3}'````

Comment: If you want actual digits in the URL, you'll have to paste on the exact digits you want. Sorry, I saw the `\d` and thought you were using regex, but this seems unrelated to regex. I'd suggest modifying your question to show a few sample outputs. Do you have a list of the "pertinent keys"?

Comment: You were right, it is using regex. The five digits and then the three digits are unknown so I wanted to use regex to go for them.

Comment: Regex would be useful to extract those digits from a list of URLs. Or test URLs to see if they have digits. If you want to paste digits onto a URL you don't need regex, and you shouldn't be using regex. Regex won't help with that. You just need `paste()` the the vector of digits. Maybe you just want `URLs <- paste0("https://www.abc-corp.com/data/", vec, "/gotit/", "12345", "22", "123")` or maybe you have a vector of digits and you need some or all combinations--I can't tell.

Comment: To scrape I need to include those digits. They are the one aspect of the URL that is difficult to pre-determine and I don't know them so I was hoping a loop could use regex to interrogate the URL and find it satisfactory enough to action the download.

Comment: You either need a list of URLs with digits and you can use regex to extract the digits. Or you need a list of digits and you can `paste` together the appropriate URLs with no regex needed. In your question you show neither of those, and I'm not sure whether you have them. In either case, you've accepted an answer indicating this question is resolved. If you still need help, I'd recommend asking a new question. In the new question, make it clear what is your input and what is your desired output. I'll stop replying to comments on this old question as it doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add 2 backslashes for each individual slash. Additionally you may want to use quantifiers instead of repeating `\d`.

```r
URLs <- paste0("https://www.abc-corp.com/data/", vec, "/gotit/", "\\d{5}", "22", "\\d{3}")
```